# Domain in cookies

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers, browser

I'm not sure so please explaine me if you know. I have problem with domain in Cookies.

According to the newewst rfc 6265 document it doesn't matter if domain in cookie starting with 'dot' or not.

For example:

Set-Cookie: example.com means the same as .example.com and it's valid for all subdomains like something.example.com and of course example.com .

So I have a question. How about "www"... If client have cookie setting to www.example.com -> client shouldn't send cookie for "example.com"??? But should send to: www.example.com???

Or maybe "www." is ignored too?

Could you explain me that? I can't find the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm asking about "www." because it's weird for me. For example www.stackoverflow.com is THE SAME as stackoverflow.com... So "www." should be ignored in my opinion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing special about `www`; it works the same as any other subdomain. `www.example.com` is different to `example.com` as far as cookies are concerned. Regardless of your opinion, that is the fact. `www` as a subdomain is not special.

This is an important point, and does catch a lot of beginners out, particularly when they write links in their sites with the full domain name. If you navigate from `www.example.com/index.html` to `example.com/nextpage.html`, your cookies may not be visible on the second page if the cookies were created on the index page in the `www` subdomain.

You say you've already read the RFC, but you might find that [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com) gives a little more clarification on it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: no worries; glad I can help.  (ps - if it was helpful, an up-vote as well as the tick to accept would be nice ;-))